# RegEx/Python.findall() - Match something only if it appears before something else

Tags: python, regex, findall

I promise I checked other questions, but I can't seem to find something that applies to my particular problem. I'm trying to match a pattern only if it appears before some other substring, but both the pattern that I'm trying to match and the substring appear in the file a lot of times. I'm trying to do this with Python's re.findall() function

I have this python code and a very long file to parse. I added a comment to explain what I'm trying to do and where, and hopefully I haven't been too ambiguous.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
names = re.findall('CSRN' + r':+([A-Z ]*)' + r'\+:*'
                 + 'CGVN' + r':+([A-Z ]*)'
                 # + what's underneath only if it appears before an occurence of 'IRV',
                 # otherwise skip and try to find next pattern
                 + 'STGN' + ':([0-9a-zA-Z]*)'
                 + r'(?:OLD\+' + 'STGN' + ':([0-9a-zA-Z]*))?', text, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: sample input would be better.

Comment: use positive lookahead.(?=regex)regex1.Match regex1 only if regex matches.

Comment: Sounds like a job for lookahead indeed, but give some examples of what **should** and **shouldn't** match.

Comment: @vks the problem is that 'regex' will match anyway because it will be there at some point because both 'regex' and 'regex1' appear in the file a lot of times.

Comment: @AvinashRaj here's a snippet of the input, but it's quite confusing http://pastee.co/mZVtth

Comment: @funkwurm I did try lookahead stuff, but can't seem to get what I need. I posted the input above, but I know it's a bit confusing

Comment: That's the text you search _through_, I'm wondering which parts you **do** and **don't** want to find in that text.

Comment: @funkwurm The names after CSRN and CGVN, and the numbers after STGN only if they appear before 'IRV' (sometimes there's no STGN number before an IRV occurrence) - otherwise, skip those names, and try to find the next names that may have STGN number. 

Thinking about it, I should've searched for STGN and then get the names instead of the other way around, but is there any way to do it like it is right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex gets me the "last" STGN number before every IRV-occurrence, which I think is what you're asking for.

```
STGN:([0-9A-F]+)(?=(?:[^S]|S(?!TGN))*IRV)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Kmtq55Qo1DsnqP4B)

I don't understand how this relates to the names you wanna find but maybe this'll help you under way.

Brief notes:

- `[0-9A-F]` finds hexadecimal numbers, which I think you're working with here
- Basically this regex is saying "give me the STGN number followed by anything that isn't STGN and then IRV"

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to vote you up, but thanks for this - this helped me figure it out. Cheers~

Comment: We all started off with little reputation ;) But tip: edit your question rather than just commenting. For example that pastee link, just put it in the question so new readers see it immediately. Also give the concrete snippet you're trying to match rather than describing it, the regex already describes it but that's where the issue is.